# How do I upload photos into my assets list/library?

Tags: assets, upload

I get the following error message when I try to upload the photo:

"Upload failed. The error message was: Error uploading the file: The file system path "/home/tramweb/public_html/craft/assets/content/" set for this source does not exist."

Comment: Have you created that directory? If not, you need to.

Comment: @Marion I think you're right and this should resolve that error. On the other hand I always wondered why Craft is able to dynamically create sub-folders for assets but the source's root folder has to be created manually.

Comment: @carlcs I assume it's because the root folder can be Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage etc., and maybe some of those are not so easy to create.

Answer (score 4):

Have you created that directory? If not, you need to. Also be sure the directory you create has the correct permissionss (writable by the web server)

Comment: Also, make sure that you have the correct permissions to upload once you have created the directory.